# Store data on localStorage and save on the database

Tags: php, reactjs, local-storage

It is possible to save data from local storage into database? Then what is the best way to do this. My example is not working.

The error thrown by axios is 403 forbidden. However, when I tried to send a normal data not on local storage it works fine. Really appreciate your help.

```
 function saveList(){

    const item = localStorage.getItem('list');

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('type','savelist');
    formData.append('data',item);
    axios.post('/request.php',formData)
   .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
   .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });return;
 }
```

Comment: the data is stringified , you might need to change it to a JSON format for it work

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I tried to send a normal data not on local storage it works fine.

Data is returned as **String** from the localStorage, when you invoke `getItem` function.

You may want to use `JSON.parse()` to parse the string literal before sending it to the database.